# Forgot to mention one day holiday job for background check info

Tags: new-job, new-hires

So I'm going through a background check process and I submitted information from the past few years.  However, I forgot to mention a retail job that was only for one day for black friday. Should I mention this or just leave it? The place said they already finished the background check report and gave it to the company to review.  This might sound silly but I guess a job that lasted one day shouldn't matter? I didn't include it in my resume either. I just needed some extra money.

Comment: Just don't forget it when filling in your tax forms, because the tax office does care (about the money).

Answer (score 8):

Just leave it.

The background check usually is just a credit and criminal background check, plus calling your references and verifying employment.

If you were getting a security clearance for federal contract work, it might be an issue.

Comment: I doubt even this was for a federal agency that it would be an issue.  If it was it was an honest mistake, you explain you forgot, and you make the required change.